# No method 'Where' exists on type 'System.Linq.IQueryable'

Tags: c#, linq

I have function do dynamic linq where to dbset on dbcontext but get error No method 'Where' exists on type `System.Linq.IQueryable`
I don't now!!!

```
using System.Linq;

public virtual Queryable _List(string fieldNames="", string values="")
{
    _Db = Contex.Set<T>();
    var type = typeof(T);
    var property = type.GetProperty(fieldNames);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
    var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);

    var body2 = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        "Where",
        // I things this line no good but I don't now ...
        new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType },
        _Db.Expression,
        Expression.Quote(orderByExp));
    var m = _Db.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(body2);
    return m;
}
```

Comment: are you `using System.Linq;`?

Comment: yes i using system.linq;

Answer (score 2):

There's no overload of `Queryable.Where` that has two type parameters. You're probably using this method:

```
IQueryable<TSource> Where<TSource> (this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
```

Which means you should replace the line:

```
new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType },
```

With:

```
new Type[] { type }, // this is TSource
```

Comment: yes after change new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType }, by new Type[] { type },  get egain error No method 'Where' exists on type 'System.Linq.IQueryable'

Comment: Does anybody know solution? I have same problame. I want to create Dynamic expresion like this: firstTable.Where(a => secondTable.Where(b => b.ParentId == a.Id))